# Using eval and require

Tags: javascript, eval, require, webpack

I have a javascript object that stores strings and a string which contains a require statement (in _availComponents). However when I try to use eval to execute the string, it says

```
require is not defined
```

This is the code I'm using `module.exports = Manager` with webpack. Obviously scope is an issue, but I'm not sure how to make require available in the scope where eval executes.

```
var Manager = Backbone.Model.extend({

    _availComponents: {
        'test': "require('../components/test/Test')",
        'test2': '../components/test/Test'
    },

    _loadedComponents: {},

    initialize: function (options) {
        var scope = this;
        var opt = options || {};
        if (opt.startWith) {
            _.each(opt.startWith, function (compId) {
                if (scope._availComponents[compId]) {
                    scope._loadedComponents[compId] = eval(scope._availComponents[compId]);
                    scope._startComponent(new scope._loadedComponents[compId]());
                    // EDIT1: I can use the following just fine
                    var test = require('../components/test/Test');
                    // EDIT2: I cannot use the following ("module not found")
                    var test2 = require(scope._availComponents['test2']);
                }
            })
        }
        return this;
    });
```

What I want to achieve is to require the modules only at the time I need them. And I'm looking for a way to identify/require them without doing "if(X) require(../X)".

Comment: eval runs on the current scope, so just make sure that requirejs is defined in that scope..

Comment: see my EDIT1 comment I added and also, Im not using requireJS